# Breadcrumb navigation for a grails app

Tags: navigation, menu, grails-plugin, breadcrumbs

for my first grails project i like use a breadcrumb navigation.
The only plugin i found so far is [menu plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/menus)

With this plugin i was only able to create a static menu structure using 
the CRUD web interface. But the generated menu has its own web page, like a sitemap, and i have no clue who to integrate it into my existing web site.

Does anybody knows a better plugin, or an approach that would be more dynamic?

Thanks Stefan

Answer (score 2):

The grails breadcrumbs plugin works great.
http://www.grails.org/plugin/breadcrumbs

It requires the jQuery plugin.

I put this in the head of my main.gsp layout

```
    <g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
    <crumbs:resources/>
```

and this in the body

```
    <h1 id="pageName"><g:layoutTitle default="Grails" /></h1>
    <crumbs:trail selector="#pageName"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a newer Breadcrumbs Grails plugin here:

https://grails.org/plugin/groovy-breadcrumbs-plugin